# XML parsing issue with jaxb

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, jaxb2

I am new to jaxb need some help on it.

I am getting null values as out put when trying to execute the below code.could some one please guide me how to achieve the expected out put.

Actual XMl I am trying to unmarshall:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <customer >
    <cash xmlns:cash="uri:cash" >   
        <cash:no>10</cash:no>
        <cash:name>naveen</cash:name>
        <cash:age>27</cash:age>
        <cash:phno>9176927613</cash:phno>   
    </cash>
</customer>
```

Mapping classes I am using:

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;

@XmlRootElement(name="cash")
public class Cash {
    private int no;
    private String name;
    private int age;
    private Long phno;
    public int getNo() {
        return no;
    }
    @XmlElement(name="cash:no",nillable=true)
    public void setNo(int no) {
        this.no = no;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    @XmlElement(name="cash:name",nillable=true)
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }
    @XmlElement(name="cash:age",nillable=true)
    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
    public Long getPhno() {
        return phno;
    }
    @XmlElement(name="cash:phno",nillable=true)
    public void setPhno(Long phno) {
        this.phno = phno;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Cash [no=" + no + ", name=" + name + ", age=" + age + ", phno="
                + phno + "]";
    }
}
```

Customer DTO:

```
import java.util.List;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement(name="customer")

public class Customer {

    private List<Cash> cash;

    public List<Cash> getCash() {
        return cash;
    }
    @XmlElement(name="cash")
    public void setCash(List<Cash> cash) {
        this.cash = cash;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Customer [cash=" + cash +  "]";
    }
}
```

Marshalling block:

```
File  file = new File("cust.xml");  

JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Customer.class);

Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();  

Customer que= (Customer) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(file);

System.out.println(que);
```

Actual output: `Customer [cash=[Cash [no=0, name=null, age=0, phno=null]]]`

Expected output is the actual XML data.

Comment: Below is the link to a tutorial which does the same. I am not near my computer to see what might be wrong. Please compare your code and you should be narrow down the issue. https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/02/jaxb-tutorial-getting-started.html

Answer (score 0):

On the Cash class, instead of
`@XmlElement(name="cash:no",nillable=true)`

try removing `cash:` from the name value: `@XmlElement(name="no",nillable=true)`

This produced : `Customer [cash=[Cash [no=10, name=naveen, age=27, phno=9176927613]]]`

Another alternative is to add the namespace to the annotation:

`@XmlElement ( name = "no", namespace = "uri:cash" , nillable = true )`

To get more insight add a `DefaultValidationEventHandler` to the unmarshaller:

```
jaxbUnmarshaller.setEventHandler(new javax.xml.bind.helpers.DefaultValidationEventHandler());
```

This will output:

```
javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"uri:cash", local:"no"). Expected elements are <{uri:cash}phno>,<{uri:cash}age>,<{uri:cash}name>,<{}cash:no>
DefaultValidationEventHandler: [ERROR]: unexpected element (uri:"uri:cash", local:"no"). Expected elements are <{uri:cash}phno>,<{uri:cash}age>,<{uri:cash}name>,<{}cash:no>
```

According to the @XMLElement annotation, `{}cash:no` is expected, but the xml parsed out a local name of `no` and not `cash:no`

(Did this in JDK 8)

====

Using JDK 1.6.0_65 I ran three variations on the @XMLElement on the Cash.no property.  This produced two failures and a success.  Using a standard Java maven project.  No other changes to my environment.

1 @XmlElement ( name = "cash:no", nillable = true )

The original code.

```
DefaultValidationEventHandler: [ERROR]: unexpected element (uri:"uri:cash", local:"no"). Expected elements are <{}cash:no>,<{}cash:phno>,<{}cash:name>,<{}cashage>
```

2    @XmlElement ( name = "no", nillable = true )

```
DefaultValidationEventHandler: [ERROR]: unexpected element (uri:"uri:cash", local:"no"). Expected elements are <{}no>,<{}cash:phno>,<{}cash:name>,<{}cash:age>
```

3 @XmlElement ( name = "no", namespace = "uri:cash", nillable = true )

```
DefaultValidationEventHandler: [ERROR]: unexpected element (uri:"uri:cash", local:"name"). Expected elements are <{}cash:phno>,<{}cash:name>,<{uri:cash}no>,<{}cash:age>
```

Run 3 experienced the unexpected element as the first two runs but it's on Cash.name property.

Comment: thanks for your suggession, but your approch one didn't work. By the way we are working on jdk 6.

Comment: What did the DefaultValidationEventHandler produce in the console output when you ran it?

Comment: Hi naveenR, were you able to find an answer?  just wondering what the solution ended up being. thanks